# how to Repeat word in words

Tags: javascript, foreach, split, repeat, cpu-word

```js
let str = 'react';
let newStr = str.split('');
const final = newStr.forEach((word,i) =>{
    const rep = word.repeat(i) + word;
    console.log(rep);
})
```

i already did repeat it but i want to have this output { react eeact aaact cccct ttttt } not  this {r ee aaa cccc ttttt}

Comment: `word.repeat(i) + str.slice(i);`

Comment: Btw you can compact this a bit more: `let str = 'react'; Array.prototype.forEach.call(str, (word, i, full) => void console.log(word.repeat(i) + full.slice(i)));`. Note that both `String.prototype.split` and this destroy surrogate pairs, which may not be what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```js
const str = 'react';
const newStr = str.split('');
const final = newStr.map((word,i,a) => [word.repeat(i), ...a.slice(i)].join(''));

console.log(final);
```

Comment: You could have used `const final = [...str].map(`

Comment: just continued from exiting code ...

Comment: great tips thanks guys